# faster way to compare dictionaries than using set

Tags: python, dictionary, set

I have two large dictionaries with unique keys but possibly overlapping values. I want to compare each set of dictionary values against each other and find the number of overlaps. I have done this using two `for` loops and `set` but am wondering if there is a faster/more elegant way to do this.

```
dic1 = {'a': ['1','2','3'], 'b':['4','5','6'], 'c':['7','8','9']}
dic2 = {'d': ['1','8','9'], 'e':['10','11','12'], 'f':['7','8','9']}

final_list=[]
for key1  in dic1:
    temp=[]    
    for key2 in dic2:
        test  = set(dic1[key1])
        query = set(dic2[key2])
        x = len(test & query)
        temp.append( [key2, x] )
    final_list.append([key1, temp])
```

Comment: There's an error in the last line. Did you mean `final_list.append([key1, temp])`?

Comment: Are you really comparing every key in dic1 against every key in dic2?  That's what they call **O** n^2.  It's inherently slow.

Comment: @S.Lott. Yes. I am looking to compare all-against-all. However there may be a way that I can reduce this to all-against-subset - which I can pursue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to "invert" one (or both) of your dictionaries.

```
val1 = defaultdict(list)
for k in dic1:
    for v in dic1[k]:
        val[v].append( k )
# val1 is a dictionary with each value mapped to the list of keys that contain that value.

for k in dic2: 
    for v in dic2[k]:
        val1[v] is the list of all keys in dic1 that have this value
```

Comment: i like this idea. I think it will work nicely as my two dictionaries differ in size. I can "invert" the small one and loop through the big one.

Comment: @zach: Exactly backwards.  Invert the large one.  Loop through the small one.  It will be faster.